# Angular 4 How do I use another modules components in a sibling modules component

Tags: javascript, angular, module, components

So just a little background, I am using Angular 4 and the AngularCli. The following is how my folders are structured:

`app
   helper-components
      helper-components.module.ts
   views
      admin
         admin.module.ts
      views.module.js`

So basically the `admin` directory has a few view components. `helper-components` directory has a bunch of components for structural parts of the site like navigation. Inside `admin` directory are the actual views of the admin section of the website. Essentially I want to expose the components from `helper-components` directory for use inside of the view components in the `admin` directory.

I've read docs that say you need to import the module into the component you want to use it in. I tried importing the `HelperComponentsModule` into both the `ViewsModule` and the `AdminModule`. I've also tried importing it into the `AppModule`.

I continue to get the error that the component I am trying to use from the `HelperComponentsModule`, `is not a known element`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly export the components of the `HelperComponentsModule`, that you want to use in other modules.

Have a look at the [Sharing Modules docs](https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules):

```
@NgModule({
 imports:      [ CommonModule ],
 declarations: [ CustomerComponent, NewItemDirective, OrdersPipe ],
 exports:      [ CustomerComponent, NewItemDirective, OrdersPipe,
                 CommonModule, FormsModule ]
})
```